# android shell /system/bin/sh subshell not working

Tags: shell

The script

```
#!/system/bin/sh
/system/bin/busybox find . 
f=$(/system/bin/busybox find .)
echo $f
for f in $(/system/bin/busybox find .) 
do 
 echo $f
done
```

does not work as expected in my environment.
I get:

```
.
./loop.sh
```

while

```
bash loop.sh 
.
./loop.sh
. ./loop.sh
.
./loop.sh
```

is the result for the equivalent on a linux box:

```
#!/bin/sh
find . 
f=$(find .)
echo $f
for f in $(find .) 
do 
 echo $f
done
```

**What can I do about this?**

The environment is:

```
getprop ro.build.version.sdk 
22
getprop ro.build.version.release 
5.1.1
busybox
BusyBox v1.22.1 (2014-09-16 09:27:06 CST) multi-call binary.
busybox uname -a
Linux localhost 3.14.0 #68 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 18 10:27:06 CST 2017 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Maybe you're comparing apples with peaches here, as `/bin/sh` is something else than `/bin/bash` (e.g. doesn't support as many things as Bash does). Have you tried how that script works on Linux when using `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash`? Or on your Android device when using Bash (if you have it available there that is)?

Comment: @lzzy - thank you for looking into this. On linux the /bin/sh doesn't make any difference. I would love to try out bash on my android device but i don't see how i could try it out without e.g. installing a full debian or a different busybox version. For the time being I'd love to understand what's going on that such a basic function like subshell doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: Making no difference means it works the same as with Bash – or the same as with `sh` on the Android device? As for Bash on Android: [my corresponding app list](//android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_sysmaint#group_1007) says there is e.g. [Bash Shell X](//play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitcubate.android.bash.installer) you could give a try (if you don't mind it coming with AdMob; otherwise [Termius](//play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.server.auditor.ssh.client) also includes a local Bash).

Comment: I guess it's because BusyBox has a different version of `find` compared to your Linux Distro.. BTW, what is your script trying to achieve? If it's simply listing the contents of a directory, you could better use `ls`, and pipe it to `grep` for searching..

Comment: it doesn't make any difference what subshell command I call. the subshell $() doesn't work as expected ..